# Sum between range

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to sum qty between @p and @p2 and between @p and @p3.
but the result of between @p and @p3 just sum between @p2 and @p3 only.

```
create table #t(time varchar(10),qty int)

declare @p varchar=1
declare @p1 varchar=2
declare @p3 varchar=3

select case when time between @p and @p1 then 1
            when time between @p and @p3 then 2  end
            ,SUM(qty)
from #t group by (case when time between @p and @p1 then 1 
                  when time between @p and @p3 then 2  end)
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UNION` to get the results in 3 rows, same format as your attempt:

```
select filtering = 1, total = sum(qty)
from #t where time between @p and @p1 
union all
select filtering = 2, total = sum(qty)
from #t where time between @p and @p3 
union all
select filtering = null, total = sum(qty)
from #t ;
```

or 3 aggregates with different filters to get them in 3 columns:

```
select 
    total_1 = sum(case when time between @p and @p1 then qty else 0 end),
    total_2 = sum(case when time between @p and @p3 then qty else 0 end),
    total_all = sum(qty)
from #t ;
```

Comment: The second approach with SUM(case) scales better from a performance point of view:
First query with union all: 3 scans...at least 3 logical reads (with my tiny sample data). Second query with SUM(case) 1 scan.,..at least 1 logical read. That means that query 1 needs 3times the resources than query 2 needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that your CASE statement is ambigious. If the value is @p or @p1 both case when expressions will be true. In that case just the first one hit (returns 1) is going to be evaluated. There are two alternative ways I could think of:

- use two subqueries to do the sum
- use windowing functions to calculate a running total (since your values are additive).

The latter would be probably more efficient as you need table access just once.

Something like:

```
create table #t(time varchar(10),qty int)

declare @p varchar=1;
declare @p1 varchar=2;
declare @p3 varchar=3;

insert into #t 
values
(
    '1', 10
),
(
    '2', 20
),
(
    '3', 30
)
;

SELECT 
    [time],
    qty,
    SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS runningTotal
FROM
    #t
```

Then the rows for time 2 and time 3 are the results you would like to obtain:
[image]

By the way: Having a time as datatype varchar(10) sounds a little bit odd. Datetime would seem to be more fitting. Have a look [here](http://sqlkover.com/t-sql-tuesday-99-door-2/) for advice.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I got error message Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: Sorry my bad...order on window functions using aggregates like SUM was introduced with SQL Server 2017. You should be fine with the approaches from ypercube's answer.